# PHP Encoding Query on Redirect

Tags: php, redirect

I'm trying ot redirect from a page with the query included but when it redirects from the page the query changes. Before the redirect my query looks like this:

`&utm_pageurl=[PAGE-URL]&utm_pagedomain=[PAGE-DOMAIN]`

but it turns out like this:

`utm_pageurl=%5BPAGE-URL%5D&utm_pagedomain=%5BPAGE-DOMAIN%5D`

Here is the code being used to redirect:

```
$newquery = "?" . http_build_query($_GET);
header("Location: Http://" . $sref . $newquery );
```

`$sref` is just the URL to the page before the query How do i stop the URL encoding?

Comment: You could avoid using `http_build_query`. But it's not clear why you'd want to do that. You could send the `$newquery` variable through `.replace(/%5B/g, '[').replace(/%5D/g, ']');` if all you want to do is replace the square brackets.

Comment: It's just a cosmetic difference. From the browser and server point of view, query data is exactly the same. If you don't like it, either write your own version of `http_build_query()` or write code to post-process the resulting string.

Comment: @ChrisLear where would i place the `.replace();`?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález if its just cosmetic then thats fine, I just want to make sure the URL looks the same as it did before instead of changing. If the query works correctly or not isnt as important as it looking the asme for this specific page

Comment: %5B is the same as [ read this http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$newquery = "?" . str_replace('%5B', '[', str_replace('%5D', ']', http_build_query($_GET)));

header("Location: Http://" . $sref . $newquery );
```

Answer (score 3):

This is required. `[` and `]` are reserved characters in URLs. If not encoded the request might break, for instance due to the user using a different client than you in you tests or some proxy in between messing up.

The only valid characters are `A-Za-z`, `0-9` , `-`, `.`, `_`, and `~` everythig else has to be encoded.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986

Comment: since im more concerned iwth the way the query looks instead of if it will actually work in this specific situation, how woul di place the `[` and `]` back in the URL?

Comment: If you don't want to create an URL, don't use `http_build_query()`. This might escape other values, too.